# How to get unique documents based on a record's value (PyMongo)?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

My document format is like,

```
{
    "_id" 
    "brand" :
    "im_name" :
    "product_url" :,
    "gender" :,
    "classify" :,
    "title" : ,
    "color" : ,
    "price" : ,
    "im_url" :"http://image.s5a.com/is/image/saks/0400092265571_247x329.jpg",
    "category" : 
}
```

I have duplicate records in database and it is already populated so i cannot rebuilt it.
I tried using `collection.distinct()` function on `"im_url"` but it only returns me list of distinct urls whereas I want complete object filtered with unique `"im_url"` values.